# How to query the tensorflow 'wide and deep' model using the saved_model_cli?

Tags: python, command-line, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

After following the SavedModel 'wide and deep' tutorial at https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md, I cannot seem to query the SavedModel using the saved_model_cli that comes with Tensorflow.

Here's an example of something I've already tried:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir /tmp/serving_savemodel/1504908631 --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default --input_exprs 'age=25;capital_gain=0;capital_loss=0;education=11th;education_num=7;gender=Male;hours_per_week=40;native_country=United-States;occupation=Machine-op-inspct;relationship=Own-child;workclass=Private'
```

Answer (score 2):

MtDersvan [answered](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/issues/3) the question from his [Github repo](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground), which was successful for me (avoiding quotations due to formatting errors):

Because the input is a serialized tf.Example you'll need to convert a feature_dict into a serialized proto tensor, something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def _float_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

feature_dict = {'age': _float_feature(value=25),
                'capital_gain': _float_feature(value=0),
                'capital_loss': _float_feature(value=0),
                'education': _bytes_feature(value='11th'.encode()),
                'education_num': _float_feature(value=7),
                'gender': _bytes_feature(value='Male'.encode()),
                'hours_per_week': _float_feature(value=40),
                'native_country': _bytes_feature(value='United-States'.encode()),
                'occupation': _bytes_feature(value='Machine-op-inspct'.encode()),
                'relationship': _bytes_feature(value='Own-child'.encode()),
                'workclass': _bytes_feature(value='Private'.encode())}

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))

serialized = example.SerializeToString()

serialized_proto = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(serialized, shape=[1])

serialized_proto_handle = serialized_proto.string_val
```

This serialized_proto_handle should look like this:

```
[b'\n\xaa\x02\n\x1a\n\x0ehours_per_week\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00 B\n\x1d\n\x0crelationship\x12\r\n\x0b\n\tOwn-child\n\x19\n\reducation_num\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xe0@\n#\n\noccupation\x12\x15\n\x13\n\x11Machine-op-inspct\n\x18\n\x0ccapital_gain\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x18\n\x0ccapital_loss\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x15\n\teducation\x12\x08\n\x06\n\x0411th\n\x0f\n\x03age\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xc8A\n#\n\x0enative_country\x12\x11\n\x0f\n\rUnited-States\n\x18\n\tworkclass\x12\x0b\n\t\n\x07Private\n\x12\n\x06gender\x12\x08\n\x06\n\x04Male']
```

So this can be done separately, e.g. in an ipython or a python script. Next, you can either dump it into a file (pickle, .npy, .npz) or shoot it up straight from a console:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir ./wide_and_deep_tutorial/serving_savemodel/${MODEL_DIR} \
--tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default \
--input_exprs "inputs=[b'\n\xaa\x02\n\x1a\n\x0ehours_per_week\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00 B\n\x1d\n\x0crelationship\x12\r\n\x0b\n\tOwn-child\n\x19\n\reducation_num\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xe0@\n#\n\noccupation\x12\x15\n\x13\n\x11Machine-op-inspct\n\x18\n\x0ccapital_gain\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x18\n\x0ccapital_loss\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x15\n\teducation\x12\x08\n\x06\n\x0411th\n\x0f\n\x03age\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x00\x00\xc8A\n#\n\x0enative_country\x12\x11\n\x0f\n\rUnited-States\n\x18\n\tworkclass\x12\x0b\n\t\n\x07Private\n\x12\n\x06gender\x12\x08\n\x06\n\x04Male']"

Result for output key classes:
[[b'0' b'1']]
Result for output key scores:
[[ 0.85787761  0.14212234]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. --input-exprs need to be valid Python expressions; you are missing quotes around your strings.
2. --input-exprs expects one value per input to the model; this model has a single input: a string which is expected to be a serialized `tf.train.Example` object (you can verify this using `saved_model_cli show`).

To be honest, trying to build a tf.train.Example on the command-line is onerous, and you may be better off writing a Python script to build them and store them to a file (then you can use the `--input` option instead). And in fact, the `=` is going to confuse `saved_model_cli` anyways.

Here's example Python code to build and serialize an `tf.train.Example` in a single line (it' a single int feature `x` with value 10):

```
`tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={"x": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[10]))})).SerializeToString()`
```